# Making function work for any one of the same type of element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a file upload system. This file upload system works great for the mosot part. The problem comes in because there are multiple HTML elements on the page that have class `file` and multiple HTML elements that are `upload-buttons`. Right now file uploading works great only for the first HTML element that contains the upload text field and upload button only, all others fail to work (due to Javascript selecting the [0] object every time).

My question is, how can can I adjust the function below to cater to whatever upload container / button that was used?

Essentially what needs to happen is, if the user clicks on the nth upload button the functions array slots needs to be equal to n-1 somehow.

I appreciate any assistance with this problem.

Many thanks in advance!

```
$(document).on('click','.upload-button', function(){
        var data = new FormData();

        jQuery.each($('.file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
            data.append('file-'+i, file);
        });
            //Some more code...
});
```

HTML

```
     <div class="input-text-field">
         <input name="userfile" class="file" type="file" />
         <input class="submit upload-button" type="submit" value="Upload" />
     </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `prev()` to target just the previous `.file` element, and be aware that your code does'nt have a `.file` element, it has a #file element, and multiple ID's are invalid.

```
$(document).on('click','.upload-button', function(){
        var data = new FormData();

        jQuery.each($(this).prev('.file')[0].files, function(i, file) {
            data.append('file-'+i, file);
        });
            //Some more code...
});
```

html

```
<div class="input-text-field">
     <input name="userfile" class="file" type="file" />
     <input class="submit upload-button" type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works great!! The id `file` in the HTML was a typo, I apologize for that, I fixed that in the question. Can you please explain why this JQuery code works? I'm fascinated :D Doesn't the function always get the first file element on the page regaurdless?  or with your implementation it targets all the `file` elements starting from the closest one before the upload button and we are selecting the object[0] of all of the elements?

Comment: It works because `$('.file')` selects all elements with that class, while `$(this).prev('.file')` selects ***only*** the previous element, if it has a class of `.file`. And you're welcome!